# How to group MySQL tables calculating the difference between each table's total traveled distance

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava a (very large) table on every row, the total trip, and current date is stored. So I need an appropriate solution for large number of records. For example on 2014-10-03 09:00:00 I have walked 1 kilometer then I insert the current date and 2101.00km to the totalTrip field (the totalTrip starts from 2100 and may start from any number). Next hour I made another 5km walk and stored the totalTrip as 2105.00km. Next day I walked 10 more kilometers and inserted the date 2014-10-04 05:00:00 and total trip as 2115.00km to the database.
As result I need to group the rows by days and only get the km made on each particular day. How can I do that in the shortest and efficient way and is that possible by using "group by"? I hope I could explain my situation.

*Here (sample) what I have:*

```
id     date                    totalTrip
1      2014-10-03 09:00:00     2100.23
2      2014-10-03 10:00:00     2102.33
3      2014-10-04 05:00:00     2112.35
4      2014-10-05 02:00:00     2120.37
5      2014-10-05 03:00:00     2140.41
6      2014-10-05 05:00:00     2155.45
```

*Here (sample) what I want:*

```
date         traveledDistance
2014-10-03   2.10
2014-10-04   10.03
2014-10-05   43.10
```

Comment: @Strawberry it should read 10.02 but it's (2112.35 - 2102.33), because it's the distance traveled on that day from where they left off the day before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

  CREATE TABLE my_table
  (id     INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,date                    DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,totalTrip DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
  (1      ,'2014-10-03 09:00:00',     2100.23),
  (2      ,'2014-10-03 10:00:00',     2102.33),
  (3      ,'2014-10-04 05:00:00',     2112.35),
  (4      ,'2014-10-05 02:00:00',     2120.37),
  (5      ,'2014-10-05 03:00:00',     2140.41),
  (6      ,'2014-10-05 05:00:00',     2155.45);

  SELECT DATE(a.date) date
       , SUM(a.diff) total 
    FROM 
       ( SELECT y.*
              , MIN(y.totaltrip)-x.totaltrip diff 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.id > x.id 
          GROUP 
             BY x.id
       ) a 
   GROUP 
      BY DATE(a.date);
  +--------------+-------+
  | date         | total |
  +--------------+-------+
  | 2014-10-03   |  2.10 |
  | 2014-10-04   | 10.02 |
  | 2014-10-05   | 43.10 |
  +--------------+-------+
```

Explanation: The distance travelled in each row is deducted from that of its nearest subsequent row `MIN(y.totaltrip)-x.totaltrip`. Afterwards, all these intermediate results are summed by date. That's all.

Note that if by 'very large' you actually mean 'very, very large' (very unlikely) then a solution using variables will be significantly faster.

Comment: +1 nice one. Mind giving little explanation as well. Just trying to understand.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks for the details. It will be really great if you include  the comment in your answer.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you thats great you are the best ;). by the way what do you mean by using variables? (i think it could be up to one million records perhaps more i am just trying to be ready if the unlikely situation happens :) )

Comment: 1 million? - pah, that's peanuts. We can do variables some other day.

Answer (score 1):

let's call the table 'table_name':

```
SELECT 
    foo.date, SUM(foo.totalTrip - table_name.totalTrip) AS totalTrip
FROM
    table_name
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT id - 1 AS id, date, totalTrip FROM table_name) AS foo
         ON foo.id = table_name.id
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Why the need for a limit clause?

Comment: The first row is null! try it.

Comment: I'm just wondering why it's there, it doesn't seem like it would have an affect, would it?

Comment: The first row is null because you've used LEFT JOIN, right?

Comment: You can omit it. but the first row is null.

Comment: This solution assumes that ID is contiguous (no gaps). This might be a reasonable assumption, but then again...